# How do I fix my code so it allows me to grab the user's id who entered the command?

Tags: python, mongodb, discord, discord.py

Hi I'm currently trying to make a bot with an Economy system for my Discord Bot using the MongoDB online service however I can't seem to get my code to work on using either the !balance or !work command as it keeps coming up with the following errors:

Errors:

```
2020-12-24T20:04:16.360587+00:00 app[worker.1]: Ignoring exception in command balance:
2020-12-24T20:04:16.362250+00:00 app[worker.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-12-24T20:04:16.362335+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
2020-12-24T20:04:16.362336+00:00 app[worker.1]: ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
2020-12-24T20:04:16.362369+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "bot.py", line 43, in balance
2020-12-24T20:04:16.362369+00:00 app[worker.1]: await open_account(ctx.author)
2020-12-24T20:04:16.362445+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "bot.py", line 79, in open_account
2020-12-24T20:04:16.362447+00:00 app[worker.1]: discorduserid = ctx.author
2020-12-24T20:04:16.362498+00:00 app[worker.1]: AttributeError: 'Member' object has no attribute 'author'
```

Code:

```
@bot.command()
async def balance(ctx):
    await open_account(ctx.author)
    discorduserid = str(member.id)

    results = collection.find({"userid":discorduserid})

    for result in results:
        wallet_amt = result["points"]

    em = discord.Embed(title = f"{ctx.author.name}'s balance", colour = discord.Colour.red())
    em.add_field(name = "Wallet", value = wallet_amt)
    await ctx.send(embed = em)

@bot.command()
@commands.cooldown(1, 43200, commands.BucketType.user)
async def work(ctx):
    await open_account(ctx.author)

    discorduserid = ctx.message.author

    earnings = random.randrange(500)

    await ctx.send(f"You went to work and earned {earnings} coins!")

    results = collection.update_many({"userid":discorduserid}, {"$inc":{"points":earnings}})

@work.error
async def work_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandOnCooldown):
        timerem = str(timedelta(error.retry_after/28800)).split(".")[0]
        msg1 = 'This command is on cooldown, please try again in '
        msg2 = msg1 + timerem
        await ctx.send(msg2)
    else:
        raise error

async def open_account(ctx):
    discorduserid = ctx.author

    if collection.find({"userid":discorduserid}):
        return False
    else:
        newentry = {"userid":discorduserid, "points":0}
```

> 2020-12-25T01:19:42.580307+00:00 app[worker.1]: None
> 2020-12-25T01:19:42.580471+00:00 app[worker.1]: Ignoring exception in
> on_message 2020-12-25T01:19:42.582406+00:00 app[worker.1]: Traceback
> (most recent call last): 2020-12-25T01:19:42.582440+00:00
> app[worker.1]: File
> "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py",
> line 85, in wrapped 2020-12-25T01:19:42.582440+00:00 app[worker.1]:
> ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs) 2020-12-25T01:19:42.582464+00:00
> app[worker.1]: File "bot.py", line 57, in work
> 2020-12-25T01:19:42.582464+00:00 app[worker.1]: await
> open_account(ctx.author) 2020-12-25T01:19:42.582496+00:00
> app[worker.1]: File "bot.py", line 91, in open_account
> 2020-12-25T01:19:42.582497+00:00 app[worker.1]:
> collection.insert_one(new_entry) 2020-12-25T01:19:42.582552+00:00
> app[worker.1]: NameError: name 'new_entry' is not defined
> 2020-12-25T01:19:42.582599+00:00 app[worker.1]:
> 2020-12-25T01:19:42.582600+00:00 app[worker.1]: The above exception
> was the direct cause of the following exception:
> 2020-12-25T01:19:42.582600+00:00 app[worker.1]:
> 2020-12-25T01:19:42.582639+00:00 app[worker.1]: Traceback (most recent
> call last): 2020-12-25T01:19:42.582769+00:00 app[worker.1]: File
> "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/client.py",
> line 333, in _run_event 2020-12-25T01:19:42.582771+00:00
> app[worker.1]: await coro(*args, **kwargs)
> 2020-12-25T01:19:42.582817+00:00 app[worker.1]: File
> "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py",
> line 943, in on_message 2020-12-25T01:19:42.582817+00:00
> app[worker.1]: await self.process_commands(message)
> 2020-12-25T01:19:42.582855+00:00 app[worker.1]: File
> "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py",
> line 940, in process_commands 2020-12-25T01:19:42.582856+00:00
> app[worker.1]: await self.invoke(ctx) 2020-12-25T01:19:42.582897+00:00
> app[worker.1]: File
> "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py",
> line 907, in invoke 2020-12-25T01:19:42.582897+00:00 app[worker.1]:
> await ctx.command.dispatch_error(ctx, exc)
> 2020-12-25T01:19:42.582932+00:00 app[worker.1]: File
> "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py",
> line 424, in dispatch_error 2020-12-25T01:19:42.582932+00:00
> app[worker.1]: await injected(ctx, error)
> 2020-12-25T01:19:42.582936+00:00 app[worker.1]: File
> "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py",
> line 71, in wrapped 2020-12-25T01:19:42.582937+00:00 app[worker.1]:
> ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs) 2020-12-25T01:19:42.582976+00:00
> app[worker.1]: File "bot.py", line 79, in work_error
> 2020-12-25T01:19:42.582977+00:00 app[worker.1]: raise error
> 2020-12-25T01:19:42.583009+00:00 app[worker.1]: File
> "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py",
> line 903, in invoke 2020-12-25T01:19:42.583010+00:00 app[worker.1]:
> await ctx.command.invoke(ctx) 2020-12-25T01:19:42.583047+00:00
> app[worker.1]: File
> "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py",
> line 859, in invoke 2020-12-25T01:19:42.583047+00:00 app[worker.1]:
> await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
> 2020-12-25T01:19:42.583076+00:00 app[worker.1]: File
> "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py",
> line 94, in wrapped 2020-12-25T01:19:42.583077+00:00 app[worker.1]:
> raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
> 2020-12-25T01:19:42.583137+00:00 app[worker.1]:
> discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an
> exception: NameError: name 'new_entry' is not defined
> 2020-12-25T01:19:44.629823+00:00 app[worker.1]: None
> 2020-12-25T01:19:44.630148+00:00 app[worker.1]: Ignoring exception in
> command balance: 2020-12-25T01:19:44.630460+00:00 app[worker.1]:
> Traceback (most recent call last): 2020-12-25T01:19:44.630523+00:00
> app[worker.1]: File
> "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py",
> line 85, in wrapped 2020-12-25T01:19:44.630524+00:00 app[worker.1]:
> ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs) 2020-12-25T01:19:44.630556+00:00
> app[worker.1]: File "bot.py", line 42, in balance
> 2020-12-25T01:19:44.630557+00:00 app[worker.1]: await
> open_account(ctx.author) 2020-12-25T01:19:44.630560+00:00
> app[worker.1]: File "bot.py", line 91, in open_account
> 2020-12-25T01:19:44.630560+00:00 app[worker.1]:
> collection.insert_one(new_entry) 2020-12-25T01:19:44.630625+00:00
> app[worker.1]: NameError: name 'new_entry' is not defined
> 2020-12-25T01:19:44.630677+00:00 app[worker.1]:
> 2020-12-25T01:19:44.630678+00:00 app[worker.1]: The above exception
> was the direct cause of the following exception:
> 2020-12-25T01:19:44.630678+00:00 app[worker.1]:
> 2020-12-25T01:19:44.630678+00:00 app[worker.1]: Traceback (most recent
> call last): 2020-12-25T01:19:44.630749+00:00 app[worker.1]: File
> "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py",
> line 903, in invoke 2020-12-25T01:19:44.630749+00:00 app[worker.1]:
> await ctx.command.invoke(ctx) 2020-12-25T01:19:44.630753+00:00
> app[worker.1]: File
> "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py",
> line 859, in invoke 2020-12-25T01:19:44.630754+00:00 app[worker.1]:
> await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
> 2020-12-25T01:19:44.630793+00:00 app[worker.1]: File
> "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py",
> line 94, in wrapped 2020-12-25T01:19:44.630794+00:00 app[worker.1]:
> raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
> 2020-12-25T01:19:44.630843+00:00 app[worker.1]:
> discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an
> exception: NameError: name 'new_entry' is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read your code and found a few issues, try this code that I modified from yours

```
@bot.command()
async def balance(ctx):
    await open_account(ctx.author)
    discorduserid = ctx.author.id

    document = collection.find_one({"userid":discorduserid})
    print(document)

    wallet_amt = document["points"]

    em = discord.Embed(title = f"{ctx.author.name}'s balance", colour = discord.Colour.red())
    em.add_field(name = "Wallet", value = wallet_amt)
    await ctx.send(embed = em)

@bot.command()
@commands.cooldown(1, 43200, commands.BucketType.user)
async def work(ctx):
    await open_account(ctx.author)

    discorduserid = ctx.author.id

    earnings = random.randrange(500)

    await ctx.send(f"You went to work and earned {earnings} coins!")
    doc = collection.find_one({"userid":discorduserid}})

    total_earnings = doc["points] + earnings
    

    results = collection.update_one({"userid":discorduserid}, {"$set":{"points":total_earnings}})

@work.error
async def work_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandOnCooldown):
        timerem = str(timedelta(error.retry_after/28800)).split(".")[0]
        msg1 = 'This command is on cooldown, please try again in '
        msg2 = msg1 + timerem
        await ctx.send(msg2)
    else:
        raise error

async def open_account(user: discord.User):
    discorduserid = user.id

    doc = collection.find_one({"userid": discorduserid})

    if doc != None:
        print(doc)
    else:
        print(doc)
        newentry = {"userid":discorduserid, "points":0}
        collection.insert_one(new_entry)
```

I hope this helps. Have a great day!

Comment: Hi hope you're having a good day too! I put in this code and it took away the majority of errors I was having however raised some new ones including;


!balance

em.add_field(name = "Wallet", value = wallet_amt)

app[worker.1]: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'wallet_amt' referenced before assignment

Comment: Alright, I changed it up slightly, tell me how it is

Comment: Looks like it's getting closer and closer with less errors! This is the only error now:


wallet_amt = document["points"]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: That's great, although, what I think is happening is that it doesn't find anything, so it returns None

Comment: OK, edited again, make sure that collection is defined tho, or it won't work. Let me know what happens

Comment: I really appreciate all the help you're giving, thank you :) It seems to still be coming up with that same issue sadly

Comment: Np, I edited again for troubleshooting, this time send your whole console output so I can help

Comment: Apologies for the delay! I added the full console output to the question

Comment: OK, edited again, update the error when you try it please, and sorry, but this is my last answer for the day. I'll check back tomorrow

Comment: Updated with the latest error page! Hope you have a wonderful day tomorrow

Comment: Looks like I mistyped the variable and everything is working as expected, thank you so much! Can't put into words how much this one was annoying me